# separate one link into multi-links (php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have result php page with a html table. Inside `row[3]` i have *spoilers*. if i click on a text value i can see hidden content.
 Inside hidden content i have *links* on different lines
To make this:
- I insert text inside mysql textarea, so:
[image]
- Then I add javascript code in `<head>`section

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $(".spoiler-label").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".spoiler-content").toggle();
    });
    });
</script>
```

- and then php code:

```
echo '<td><span class="spoiler-label">'.$row[1].'</span><div class="spoiler-content" style="display: none"><br><a href='.$row[3].'<a/></div><td>';
```

- To break the text in new lines i use this php code:

```
    $row['3']=stripslashes($row['3']);
    $row['3']=str_replace('<br />',"newline",$row['3']);
    $row['3']=htmlentities($row['3']);
    $row['3']=str_replace('newline',"<br>",$row['3'])
```

i obtain this final result:
[image]

but you can see the problems:
- formatting is missing because the `<th>` of row X is black and not orange
- the links inside the spoiler are 2 but are treated as if they are one link. 
- i have not correctly link because **google.com** is `http://google.com<br` WHY?
You can see 2 links:
 `http://alfa.com` 
 `http://google.com`
 but if i click over http://alfa.com the link is always `http://google.com<br`
**I want**:
-remove `<br` from link
-separate one link into different links (alfa.com & google.com) 
-repair incorrect row formatting
This is my page complete code http://pastebin.com/zb22VqwD and this css http://pastebin.com/dFRFURGM

Comment: -1 for long non-abstracted localised question; +1 for the effort of putting together a complete post with annotated graphics!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off, your 1 line php code echo is wrong (u didnt close `<a>`). The css didnt work because of this.

(i removed the first echo)

second, an `<a>` tag cannot have another `<a>` tag inside it, so you should just remove the whole `<a>` from your code above, meaning it should be:

```
echo '<td><span class="spoiler-label">'.$row[1].'</span><div class="spoiler-content" style="display: none"><br>'.$row[3].'</div><td>';
```

then, when instead of for some reason changing ur correct `<br/>`'s into the old version `<br>` tag, use the tag to create an array:

```
$ary=explode('<br />',$row['3']);
$str="";
foreach($ary as $str2){
$str.="<a href=\"$str2\">$str2</a><br/>";
}
```

and then echo `$str` into the row,

Your code should be:

```
$row['3']=str_replace('<br />',"newline",$row['3']);
$row['3']=stripslashes($row['3']);
$row['3']=htmlentities($row['3']);
$ary=explode('newline',$row['3']);
$str="";
foreach($ary as $str2){
    $str.="<a href=\"$str2\">$str2</a><br/>";
    //$str.="$str2<br/>";
}
$row['3']=$str;
```

Comment: Can u show me with my code, please? i don't undestand how code, thanks for help anyway

Comment: now the links are separated but i have still css problems and i have double links? look here http://imageshack.us/a/img266/8265/solmk.png this is my code updated http://pastebin.com/v0ysisex What did I do wrong?

Comment: i don't change <br/> into <br> could be? if so, in what sense do I change it into <br>?, what part of the code you're referring to?

Comment: actually u accidently put double the code..see my changes again. at the top, and bottom

Comment: mm..something seems to have improved, but still have some problems with the double link on **download** column download link and with css, look please http://imageshack.us/a/img713/7875/css2o.png with your correction http://pastebin.com/a3z4hpM4 what's wrong?

Comment: ok, i remove line 132. Now it's better, thanks but can i correct that black block to improve css? http://imageshack.us/a/img853/2743/css3f.png

Comment: my last request about css you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013683/remove-black-block-css-php

Answer (score 0):

You are use beolow code:

```
$row['3']=stripslashes($row['3']);
$row['3']=str_replace('<br />',"newline",$row['3']);
$row['3']=htmlentities($row['3']);
$row['3']=str_replace('newline',"<br>",$row['3'])
```

Instead of above code use below:

```
$row['3']=str_replace('<br />',"newline",$row['3']);
$row['3']=stripslashes($row['3']);
$row['3']=htmlentities($row['3']);
$row['3']=str_replace('newline',"<br>",$row['3'])
```

Just replace first line to second and second line to first..just try...hope this help..

Comment: mmm..if i try to replace **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\test\zzz\risultati0.php on line 127** is normal?