# remove black block (css,php)

Tags: php, css

i have this code for result page:
http://pastebin.com/XK3hdNYY

and this **css**
http://pastebin.com/rs22p4px

but i have a black block that has nothing to do with css. 
For example, when the code is this

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='auto' bgcolor=”#FF0000 &#8243;>" . "&nbsp;". "<b>"  . $i . "&nbsp;". "<b/>". "</td>";
echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;" . $row[1] . "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
echo "<td width='auto'>". $row[2] . "</td>";
echo '<td><span class="spoiler-label">'.$row[1].'</span><div class="spoiler-content" style="display: none"><br>'.$row[3].'</div><td>';
echo "</tr>";
```

i have this table output
[image: table1]
when i change the code like this

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='auto' bgcolor=”#FF0000 &#8243;>" . "&nbsp;". "<b>"  . $i . "&nbsp;". "<b/>". "</td>";
echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;" . $row[1] . "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
echo "<td width='auto'>". $row[2] . "</td>";
echo "<td width='auto'>". $row[3] . "</td>";
echo '<td><span class="spoiler-label">'.$row[1].'</span><div class="spoiler-content" style="display: none"><br>'.$row[3].'</div><td>';
echo "</tr>";
```

I have this output:
[image: table2]
and when i change like this

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='auto' bgcolor=”#FF0000 &#8243;>" . "&nbsp;". "<b>"  . $i . "&nbsp;". "<b/>". "</td>";
echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;" . $row[1] . "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
echo "<td width='auto'>". $row[2] . "</td>";
echo '<td><span class="spoiler-label">'.$row[1].'</span><div class="spoiler-content" style="display: none"><br>'.$row[3].'</div><td>';
echo "<td width='auto'>". $row[3] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

my output:
[image: table3]

**I want remove these black block an and the column too**. In the third case, it seems that the column has lost its borders and lines?

Comment: seems like you might be having a  proble with a table... can you post the whole code?

Comment: Do any of the rows have more than 3 columns?

Comment: In addition to what @Robert said, you also have syntax errors with `<i/>` and `<b/>` which should be `</i>` and `</b>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have an HTML syntax error:

```
echo '<td><span class="spoiler-label">'.$row[1].'</span><div class="spoiler-content" style="display: none"><br>'.$row[3].'</div><td>';
```

Should be:

```
echo '<td><span class="spoiler-label">'.$row[1].'</span><div class="spoiler-content" style="display: none"><br>'.$row[3].'</div></td>';
```

See the closing `</td>` at the end of each line. You're opening a new column mistakenly.

A new column without a `<th>` to represent it will default to a blank column like this.